# UIAlertview is not calling the right function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have this UIAlertview with tags that I am trying to use to call a function. The fogotpassword alert view shows up then the reset alertview shows up, but then when I am trying to call the NSLog(@"Password"); function by pressing the first button in reset alertview it doesn't get called. Instead, the reset alertview button pops up again. I will appreciate any help I get.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    forgotPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Error"
                                                             message:@"Your login credentials do not match"
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again"
                                                   otherButtonTitles: @"Forgot Password",nil];
    [forgotPassword show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    forgotPassword.tag = 1;
    resetPassword.tag = 2;

    if (buttonIndex == 1 && forgotPassword.tag ==1)
    {

        resetPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Forgot Password"
                                                            message:@"Email"                                                                                                            delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Reset Password", nil];
        [resetPassword setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

        [resetPassword show];

        NSLog(@"RESET");

    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1 && resetPassword.tag == 2) {
       NSLog(@"Password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is all messed up. You set both tags so both will always be true. Since you appear to have ivars for the two different alert views, get rid of the tags and do this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView == forgotPassword) {
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
            // show other alert
        }
    else if (alertView == resetPassword) {
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
            // reset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will give you a checkmark as soon as time limit is up. I just follow another stackoverflow answer and I guess it wasnt the best method

Comment: Keep in mind that using tags instead of ivars for the alert views is also perfectly fine. You just need to set the tag when you create the alert view, not in the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use tag

Try in this way

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(alertView==forgotPassword)
    NSLog(@"forgotPassword alert");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confused. You create an alert view "forgotPassword" and show it, without setting it's tag. Then, in your alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method, you explicitly set the tag on both alert views, and THEN interrogate those alert views to see what their tags are. Those tags will never change.

Instead, you should set the tag on each alert view before showing it, and then check the tag of the UIAlertView that is passed in to the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method. Something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  forgotPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Error"
                                                             message:@"Your login credentials do not match"
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again"
                                                   otherButtonTitles: @"Forgot Password",nil];
    forgotPassword.tag = 1;
    [forgotPassword show];
 }

 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView.tag ==1)
{

    resetPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Forgot Password"
                                                            message:@"Email"                                                                                                            delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Reset Password", nil];
    [resetPassword setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    resetPassword.tag = 2;
    [resetPassword show];

    NSLog(@"RESET");

}
if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView.tag == 2) {
   NSLog(@"Password");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should be using alertView.tag == 1 and alertView.tag == 2 in your methods. As you have it right now, both if statements will always be true as long as buttonIndex == 1 since you explicitly set forgotPassword.tag = 1 and resetPassword.tag = 2, then check each item.

Also, you should set the tags within your viewDidLoad unless you have some reason to keep resetting their values every time an alertView button is pressed.

Or, an easier way would be what Anand K said.

-Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Your code is redundant and in any case hasn't a sense..
You don't need to use UIAlertView as property in this case..
Use this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Error"
                                                         message:@"Your login credentials     do not match"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again"
                                               otherButtonTitles: @"Forgot Password",nil];
    alertView.tag = 1;
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        if(alertView.tag == 1)
        {

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Forgot Password"
                                                            message:@"Email"                                                                                                            delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Reset Password", nil];
            [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
            alertView.tag = 2;

            [alertView show];

            NSLog(@"RESET");

        }
    } else if (alertView.tag == 2) {
       NSLog(@"Password");
    }
}
```

This code is clean use it ;)

Comment: Why did you duplicate the answer by Duncan?

Comment: I didn't duplicate it..my code is more clean..i don't use UIAlertView as property...moreover in the Duncun's response there is 2 times "buttonIndex == 1"..my code is more efficient..you have 48k points..maybe you can easily look the important differences..